# How do I truncate the last two characters of all files in a directory?

Tags: bash, file, unix, directory, rename

So pretty simple question.  All of the files in my directory are of the form `6bfefb348d746eca288c6d62f6ebec04_0.jpg`. I want them to look like `6bfefb348d746eca288c6d62f6ebec04.jpg`. Essentially, I want to take off the `_0` at the end of every file name. How would I go about doing this with bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Perl's standalone rename command:

```
rename -n 's/..(\....)$/$1/' *
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

---

It is possible to use this standalone `rename` command with a syntax similar to `sed`'s `s/regexp/replacement/` command. In regex a `.` matches one character. `\.` matches a `.` and `$` matches end of line (here end of  filename). `(` and `)` are special characters in regex to mark a subexpression (here one `.` and three characters at the end of your filename) which then can be reused with `$1`. `sed` uses `\1` for first back-reference, rename uses `$1`.

See: [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html) with sed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain what is going on in this command?  Sorry, I have 0 experience with Perl.

Comment: @TerryMartin: I've updated my answer.